# Java Integer parseInt error

Tags: java, binary, integer, parseint

I have following problem:

I want to convert some Binary Strings to an integer:

```
eargb = Integer.parseInt(al + re + gre + blu, 2);
```

but I get following exception. Why?

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11111111111000101000100111111010"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your number (4,293,036,538) is too large to fit in a signed int (which has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647).

Try using a long instead. This has a larger range.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
long eargb = Long.parseLong(al + re + gre + blu, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your binary number exceeded Integer size. Thats  why your getting this exception

Answer (score 0):

It has been 7 months but the target answer has not been described. Also this question is leading in search engines. The above mentioned subjects are true. You should use as follow:

```
(int)Long.parseLong("11111111111000101000100111111010",2)

eargb =(int)Long.parseLong( al + re + gre + blu, 2);
```